# how to build the velodyne_indigo package for kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a noob to ROS, but am well along in the tutorials. I have a velodyne puck lite and would like to get it working on ROS kinetic. I could install ROS indigo but that would require changing my version of ubuntu to one that is supported by ROS indigo. Could anyone tell me step by step what to do to build this package manually on  xenial?
Also, any opinions on if it would be easier to just install an older version of Ubuntu would be helpful?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269933/how-to-build-the-velodyne_indigo-package-for-kinetic/) by [rohanpaleja27](https://answers.ros.org/users/31745/rohanpaleja27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install the package from source rather than binary. If you look on the [Github page](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) for the repository it states that it works with ros kinetic. To do this:

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src
git clone -b master https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne.git
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

You may have to install some dependencies etc, but the package should build fine. If you're unfamiliar with the catkin build system, have a look at the tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-31**:
I would insert a `rosdep update && rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws --ignore-src` right before `catkin_make`. That will take care of "install[ing] some dependencies etc".

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-31**:
Yep good point. I don't use rosdep but a good tool for beginners and making installs easier.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-01**:
How do you deal with dependencies of packages that you want to build from sources then?
Manually?

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-09-03**:
Yeah manually. I like to work through and install manually just to keep clear in my head what needs what etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-04**:
Then perhaps substituting `check` for `install` might be interesting.
Although I don't really see the appeal of installing things manually, I do like to know what is going on, so I always run with `check` first.